# Separable equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I had $y=e^{4\ln|x|}+e^{4C}$, then simplified to $y=e^4 \cdot e^{\ln|x|} +e^{4C}=A\ln|x|+C_2$.
This seems to be wrong and should've been $e^{\ln|x^4|}+e^{4C}$.

Why is what I initially did wrong?

This comes from the separable ODE $x \frac{dy}{dx} = 4y$ whose answer is $cx^4$.

Comment: You wrote $\exp(4\log|x|)=\exp(4)\exp(\log|x|)$ which is uncorrect.

Comment: Your calculus seems basically correct but your algebra is all over the place.  **Must know exponent laws!!!**

Comment: @Joe how is it incorrect? $A^{xy}$ = $A^x \cdot A^y$ doesn't it?

Comment: NO!! It's false!!! The rule which holds is $A^{x+y}=A^xA^y$. With multiplication is not valid.

Comment: $A^{x+y}=A^xA^y$ and $A^{xy}=(A^x)^y = (A^y)^x$

Comment: @Wood oh ya I mixed the two together. I'll take not of the rules you just wrote and memorize them.

Comment: [Recommended for careful study](http://www.maths.unsw.edu.au/sites/default/files/power-laws.pdf).

Comment: Please make by your own some examples (even numerical). If you came here to get your solution, you won't get no personal improvement.

Comment: @Joe, it looks like they *didn't* just come here for a solution. They did some work, but just made a mistake. The OP *is* improving, but we all make silly and small mistakes sometimes.

Comment: @LonelyMathematician I agree with you but not at all. However my comment didn't want to be polemical. Only constructive.

Comment: @Joe Indeed, you are right :)

Comment: @Celeritas Just a friendly reminder in case you don’t know how the site works: after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "upvote" and/or "accept" the answer by clicking the up arrow and the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question and will encourage others to answer your other questions. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: @JohnD I'm aware. It's been less than 24 hours so it seemed a little too soon to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
x{dy\over dx}&=4y\\
x\,dy&=4y\,dx\\
y^{-1}\,dy&=4x^{-1}\,dx\\
\int y^{-1}\,dy&=\int 4x^{-1}\,dx\\
\ln|y|&=4\ln|x|+C,\ C \in \mathbb{R}\\
e^{\ln|y|}&=e^{4\ln|x|+C}\\
|y|&=e^{4\ln|x|}e^{C}\\
y&=\pm e^C x^4\\
y&=Dx^4, \quad D=\pm e^C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$e^{4\ln|x|}$ **is not** $e^4 \cdot e^{\ln|x|}$ and this is the requested source of wrong solution.